# Return all fields in Ecto query as a map for sending results back as json?

Tags: json, elixir, ecto

If I don't put a select, ecto returns the full struct which makes sense but then I have to convert to a map and remove the `__meta__` field.

`from x in __MODULE__` will return list of `%MODULE{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata...,id: 1, name: "bob"}`

Is there a better solution than listing it out in the select clause like this:
 `from x in __MODULE__, select: %{x.id: id, x.name: name...}`

And if not, is there a way to dynamically generate this select clause off of the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don’t see any issue with calling [`Map.from_struct/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#from_struct/1), the proper approach would be to implement `json` encoder for the structure in question. Then you’ll be able to serialize the struct itself whenever you wish.

For [`Jason`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason) it’s fairly straightforward with [`@derive`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.Encoder.html?#module-deriving):

```elixir
defmodule MySchema do
  @derive Jason.Encoder

  schema ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@derive` module annotation with `except` options to blacklist the fields you don't want to encode to JSON.

E.g.:

```
defmodule MyStruct do
  ...
  @derive {Jason.Encoder, except: [:__meta__, ...]}
end
```

However, bear in mind that using this annotation can break application layers, since you'll be mixing presentation concerns with data representation concerns.
So, a better approach would be:

```
Protocol.derive(Jason.Encoder, NameOfTheStruct, only: [...])
Protocol.derive(Jason.Encoder, MyStruct, except: [...])
```

and you can also do this when you're not the owner of the struct.

For more information you can check [Jason](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason#differences-to-poison)'s documentation.